# Does @PostConstruct call before @Bean annotated created?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to understand lifecycle of spring bean. Does @PostConstruct annotated method called before @Bean annotated method and after all dependecies injected? Are they related?

```
@Configuration
public class MyBean{
    
    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean; //1

    @Bean
    public void testMethod() {
     ... //2
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void testPostConsturctMethod() {
     ... //3
    }
}
```

1-) Is cycle order will be 1-3-2?

```
@Configuration
public class MyBean extends MySuperClass {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean; //1

    @PostConstruct
    public void testPostConsturctMethod() {
     ... //3
    }
}

public class MySuperClass {

    @Bean
    public void testMethod() {
     ... //2
    }
}
```

2-) Does it change when @Bean annotated method is in super class and others in child? Like child's cycle begin when super's end? Or it's merged?

Comment: Why don't you test it by adding breakpoints or debug logs?

Comment: Although an `@Bean` method in an `@Component` (sort of) works, don't go down that path as it doesn't do what you think it does. Also an `@Bean` on a `void` method is pretty much useless.

Comment: @Ghokun I already tested it. They may not be related, that's why I write `Are they related?` in my question. May it works in 99 of 100, I'm trying to be sure, learning it certainly.

Comment: @M.Deinum Just an example, I didn't notice when I wrote. Thanks

Comment: @Ghokun two answer and they are not matching with eachother. how about that?

Comment: just put `system.out.println` into each and see for yourself...

Comment: @JAsgarov just answered same suggestion above.

Comment: @kaepxer You are not giving enough context. You tested and what was the result? What did you expect and was not as expected? I also agree with M. Deinum. Bean inside a component does not make much sense. It will not be proxied and new instance will be created each time.

Comment: @Ghokun In my test result was 1-3-2 but does it matter since `@PostConstruct` and `@Bean` may not even be even related? I'm not expecting anything, just trying to know it. And for bean inside a component, as I cleared it out above, it was mistake and edited my post now. Other than everything else, it's a clear and objective question, instead of making it so complicated how about to contribute for answer?